# Display image in Jsp file

Tags: java, html, image, jsp, src

I am trying to displaying an image in my jsp file. The location of the image is as such 
[image]

I have added the following code to my jsp page

```
 <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Images/JPic.jpg" width="600" height="200" align: right>
```

But still the image is not displaying , it only displays the box where the image should appear. Also i tried to create an images folder inside the web pages folder, but net beans doesn't allow me to create the folder. When creating the folder, netbeans only provide me with either source packages or test packages as location for folder.

How do i solve this so that it displays my image?(i need my images folder)

Thank you.

Comment: what did you see in your network tab of browser for this image? i mean what url does it display?

Comment: Do you mean the jsp url ? if yes it displays home.jsp

Comment: i meant the path ${pageContext.request.contextPath},can you see it's value?

Comment: Perhaps you can do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16528433 and then put the link as that dude described..

Comment: having trouble?? just write this line in jsp <p>The context path is: ${pageContext.request.contextPath}.</p> and check

Comment: @RE350 thank you for the comment. I was actually finding how to get it.

This is what it displayed : "The context path is: /JurassicPark-war."

Comment: So can you check , inside your war file,is this path correct,i mean is the image is at this location, JurassicPark-war/Images/JPic.jpg?